# How can I get elements from an array that starts with a specific string in that element?

Tags: php

This looks simple, but I just can't get it.
For example, I have an array:

```
$array = array("new phone","old bag","new laptop","old PC");
```

I want to get the elements that start with "new",

RESULT:
The elements that starts with "new" are:

```
"new phone" and "new laptop".
```

...so I have array with string elements and I want to obtain those elements that contains a specific string, doesn't matter if it starts the word as: "new phone", it can be also "phonenew",  "phnewone", "asdkodsanewasd", I just look for "new" in elements and if I find it, I print all elements that contain it.

Very bad code:(one of codes)

```
$array = array("new phone","old bag","new laptop","old PC");
$x="new";
foreach($array as $x)
{
    echo $x;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to write some code yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried a lots, I am totally new in PHP....

Comment: Great, add the code you tried (even if it doesn't work)

Comment: no here. update the question.

Comment: 1. Update the question. 2. I don't see any attempt to find the relevant element.

Comment: I follow a course, and so far I was supposed to get to arrays, small functions, but on exercises lists, this was the last exercise, and I didn t know what to do...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't matter if it starts the word as: "new phone", it can be also "phonenew", "phnewone", "asdkodsanewasd"

So you can merely use a pretty simple regex:

```
function select_from_array($searched_word) {
    $selection = [];
    foreach ($array as $string) {
        if (preg_match('/' . $searched_word . '/', $string)) {
            $selection[] = $string;
        }
    }
    return $selection;
}
```